# How to update 'Default agent pool for YAML' for a pipeline in Azure Devops using Rest API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I have tried to use the [definition update api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to try to update the 'Default agent pool for YAML' but no success. I kept receiving '200' response status code but the setting stay the same.

I have also tried to capture the actual request content when perform the update manually via UI, then pretty much copied the same content into the *Body* of the request but the result stayed the same.

Below is a sample of the request that I'm using:

Invoke-WebRequest -URI `"https://dev.azure.com/***/***/_apis/build/definitions/***?api-version=6.1-preview.7" -Method PUT -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{ Authorization = "Basic ***" } -Body '{***}'`

The body is in the JSON format of:

```
{
...
    "queue": {
        "id": 882,
        "name": "Azure Pipelines",
        "pool": {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Azure Pipelines",
            "isHosted": true
        }
    },
...
}
```

**Update**
As suggested by the Microsoft team, the feature is not supported. I have logged a suggestion for the feature [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Update-Default-agent-pool-for-YAML-of/1478478?space=21&q=Update%20%27Default%20Agent%20Pool%20YAML%27).

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be enabled now, but through a different set of properties. You can set the default pool through the following property:

```
process.phases.target.agentSpecification.identifier
```

The relevant snippet looks like this:

```
"process": {
    "phases": [
        {
            "name": "NameGoesHere",
            "target": {
                "agentSpecification": {
                    "identifier": "windows-latest"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As fair warning: I found that if I had the wrong revision number in my payload, the API will respond with a 200, but the pool won't change. This was especially noteworthy when I was trying to reset the pool through the UI to prove that the API call worked. Essentially, it's probably a good idea to do a `GET`, modify that payload, and send that to the `PUT` without any other actions in between.